# how can i add a command to put any value on an argument to echo invalid input

Tags: linux, if-statement, menu, arguments

i have to keep the yes and no choice but i want to put something that if i don't type yes or no to show that this is not possible i am new to this and not sure what to do

```
echo "Do you wish to Exit?(yes/no)"
read input
if [ "$input" == "yes" ]
then
clear
exit
elif [ "$input" == "no" ]
then 
clear 
echo "Reloaded"
echo -e "\n"
elif [ "$input" == * ]
then
echo "Invalid Input"
fi ;;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track here, the last condition check is causing issues however.

You are checking if `"$input" == *` in the last block. When you use `*` on its own like that you can get some wacky behavior. The shell tries to expand it to all the files in the current directory. This means that you will likely be giving too many arguments to the conditional and should get an error similar to  `[: too many argument` when  there are several files in the current directory. If the directory is empty except for the given script the conditional will be expanded to `elif [ "$input" == some_file.txt]` and the script will continue and exit normally without the desired output. See the bash [pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching) and [command expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Simple-Command-Expansion.html#Simple-Command-Expansion) documentation.

The simplest solution here is to use an `else` instead. This block will execute if the first two conditions are not met, and therfore `$inputs` is something other than yes or no. See the [bash conditional](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) documentation. You script should  look something like this:

```sh
echo "Do you wish to Exit?(yes/no)"
read input

if [ "$input" == "yes" ]
then
  clear
  exit
elif [ "$input" == "no" ]
then
  clear
  echo "Reloaded"
  echo -e "\n"
else
  echo "Invalid Input"
fi
```

As a final comment, you can simplify the `read` command into 1 line by leveraging the `-p` argument, from the usage:

> `-p prompt output the string PROMPT without a trailing newline before attempting to read`

So you can condense your read into `read -p 'Do you wish to Exit? (yes/no)' input`

Comment: Thank you very much for your replay. I managed to solve the problem after 30 minutes of searching something so simple.
So if i just replace the read with -p nothing will change? I mean its just to simplify it  right?

Comment: @antoniscy Yes! No change in work flow or functionality, just a tad more concise